# dependency injection from config file return null

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

### application.yml

```
 app:
     dbValues: "{connection_string='jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl',username='${app.username}' password='${app.password}' }"
   username: HR
   password: ******
```

I have to inject these values from the config file by using @ConfigurationProerties

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DbSetting
{
     private Map<String,String> dbValues;
     private String userName;
     private String password;

}
```

In this case String values are returned from the config file and dbValues is null which type is Map.

it is working with @Value annotation

```
   @Value("#{${app.dbValues}}")
   private Map<String,String> dbValues;
```

1. Why does the null value return through Map type when using @ConfigurationProperties annotation? What is wrong in the code?

Comment: Make it `@ConfigurationProperties("app. dbValues")`

Comment: You have given app prefix  in the conifguration properties and then in Values also you are giving app. dbValues . it should be dbValues.

Comment: I guess there is indentation issue with application.yml, align `dbValue` as username and password.